# if 11pm call function to change form input value

Tags: javascript, forms, date, time

If a user is using my site between 11pm and 12pm their local time (system time anyway) I need to **change a value** in an HTML form.

Currently I do this like this:

```
<a id="dayLink" class="tooltip" name="dayLink"  onclick='javascript: document.getElementById("day").value++; window.alert("date has been advanced by 1 day.");'>
```

This works but it requires that the user **see** the link, **hover** over it to **read** the tool tip, then **click** the link to change the value.

I would like to **automate** this so that it happens in the background without the user even knowing.

**This is what ive tried:**

```
window.onload=function(){
 myMonthFunction();
 myDayFunction();

}



function myDayFunction()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var x = document.getElementById("day");
    x.value=d.getDate();

    y.value=hours[d.getHours()];

    if (y == 11){

      document.getElementById("day").value++; 
      window.alert("date has been advanced by 1 day.");

    }
}
```

**window.alert gets called** for sure (just there for testing) but the value of **day is not incremented**. Im not sure why this works as a link but not as a function. Anyone see what im doing wrong?

---

**What worked in the end:**

```
function myDayFunction()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var x = document.getElementById("day");
    x.value=d.getDate();

    var hours = d.getHours()

    if (hours == 23){

      document.getElementById("day").value++; 
      window.alert("date has been advanced by 1 day.");
}
```

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("day").value=d.getDate()+1`

Comment: Where did `onclick="javascript: ...` originate? It spreads like a disease. I'm not commenting on the usage of the event attributes but the `javascript:` part is totally unneccessary. Not even w3shools advocates this.

Comment: lol Sorry Jan just something I found on the net to solve the problem originally till I had more time to look into it.

Comment: @techfoobar you nailed it, i forgot `var y = document.getElementById("day");` it works now. if you post that as an answer Ill accept it. Thank you very much!

Comment: *Not even w3shools advocates this* - :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `y` is not defined in the code you posted. So when you attempt `y.value = ...` it won't execute, since y is undefined. you can correct it by defining y before it is used.

Or in your case, since you already have that very element cached in `x`, you can use x itself.

Comment: actually the x and y being the same was a typo I had to fix. I tweaked my code a bit and got it running from there once you made me aware of y not having been declared. I posted my final code above. Thanks again!